# JSONAPI: is it correct to have different types in data[]?

Tags: specifications, json-api, jsonapi-resources

is it correct to have different types in data array ? didn't found answer in specification, but looks wrong.

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "type1",
      "id": "id1"
    },

    {
      "type": "type2",
      "id": "id2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphic collections are supported by JSON:API specification. Your example is a valid JSON:API document.

This is not mentioned explicitly in the specification. It is only implicitly stated by *not* requiring all resource objects included as primary data to have the same type.

Please note that it could even include two resource objects with the same `id` as long as they have different `type`.

Comment: here is another conversation confirming this answer https://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/returning-multiple-types-in-same-response/934